# How can i make SetText in my TextView in my Fragment layout from String ' "view.find.." not work for me '

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, view, nullpointerexception

hello every one i want to set text from shared preference file to string to Text view  in my Fragment layout but when i try to get data from shared preference file and put it in string and from string to text view by set text  i faced problem null pointer like values i gived to him is null how can i d that ?

*Fragment.java*

[image]

*fragment.xml*

[image]

and

logcat Error

[image]

Comment: One of the textviews is null, check if your `textview`'s ids are all correct

Comment: Please put the relevant information into your question as text instead of linking to images. Text can be found in searches.

Comment: ok @RolandWeber i beginner i tried to put but give me some errors and i convert to image and Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container,false)
```

You are passing **fragment_home** instead in fragment_profile.

Just change it to **fragment_profile:**

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container,false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `R.layout.fragment_home` with `R.layout.fragment_profile` in ProfileFragment.java

**Error Reason:**

You are inflating `fragment_home` xml layout in `ProfileFragment.java` and trying to access `textview` widget from `fragment_profile`